# How to answer automatically and programatically an incoming call on android

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I am trying to answer automatically incoming calls on my app once they are detected. My app already detects when I have an incoming call, but still does not answer the phone call. I am using the telephonyManager and I have red this tutorial [Answer incoming call using android.telecom and InCallService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767460/answer-incoming-call-using-android-telecom-and-incallservice), this one [Answer Incoming Call in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438992/answer-incoming-call-in-android-6-0), and this one [Can't answer incoming call in android marshmallow 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339534/cant-answer-incoming-call-in-android-marshmallow-6-0?noredirect=1&lq=1). If anyone knows how to do it please tell me. I do not mind change my code I just want it done, here my code.

Class where I detect my incoming calls and where I try to auto-answer the incoming calls

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telecom.Log;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.IOException;

public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TelephonyMethods.AnswerRinginCall(telephonyManager);//method that should answer incoming calls 

            }
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Received!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "IDL!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Class where I call to the answerRingingCall() method of the telephonyManager class

```
public class TelephonyMethods {

    public static void AnswerRinginCall(final TelephonyManager manager){
           manager.answerRingingCall();
    }


}
```

Method of the telephonyMnager class

```
 /** @hide */
    @SystemApi
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)
    public void answerRingingCall() {
        try {
            ITelephony telephony = getITelephony();
            if (telephony != null)
                telephony.answerRingingCall();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error calling ITelephony#answerRingingCall", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: android 6.0 you have handle run time permissions

Comment: this what I am using because of those times I have failed

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCEPT_HANDOVER"></uses-permission>

Comment: <receiver android:name="InterceptCall">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968813/i-am-checking-call-permission-in-marshmallow

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Comment: so once I check my permissions what mr @sasikumar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on same requirement, hereby sharing entire class which works fine for all API versions.

```
public class CallManager {
    private static final String TAG = CallManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private Context context;

    public CallManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    public void acceptCall() {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
                if (telecomManager != null) {
                    telecomManager.acceptRingingCall();
                }
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                throughMediaController(context);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                throughAudioManager();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throughReceiver(context);
        }
    }

    private ITelephony getTelephonyService(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            return (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void throughTelephonyService(Context context) {
        ITelephony telephonyService = getTelephonyService(context);
        if (telephonyService != null) {
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
        }
    }

    private void throughAudioManager() {
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
        audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);
        audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }

    private void throughReceiver(Context context) {
        try {
            throughTelephonyService(context);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            boolean broadcastConnected = "HTC".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)
                    && !audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();

            if (broadcastConnected) {
                broadcastHeadsetConnected(false, context);
            }
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throughPhoneHeadsetHook(context);
            } finally {
                if (broadcastConnected) {
                    broadcastHeadsetConnected(false, context);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void broadcastHeadsetConnected(boolean connected, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        intent.putExtra("state", connected ? 1 : 0);
        intent.putExtra("name", "mysms");
        try {
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void throughMediaController(Context context) {
        MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
        try {
            List<MediaController> controllers = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(new ComponentName(context, NotificationService.class));
            for (MediaController controller : controllers) {
                if ("com.android.server.telecom".equals(controller.getPackageName())) {
                    controller.dispatchMediaButtonEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throughAudioManager();
        }
    }

    private void throughPhoneHeadsetHook(Context context) {
        Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }
}
```

Just simply call the acceptCall method like below

```
CallManager callManager = new CallManager(this);
callManager.acceptCall();
```

Comment: @JuanAntonioSánchezJiménez Awesome !! glad to know could solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but where do you get NotificationService ? Is it class written by you but not cited here or is it implementation of NotificationListenerService or is it some imported class (from what package) ?

Comment: @ArturŁysik yes `NotificationService` was a customized service which extends `NotificationListenerService`. You could simply use `NotificationListenerService`