# how to accept incoming call on button click

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Caller Screen App in which I have two buttons accept and reject the call. Button reject is working properly, but the accept button is not working in all android version

```
iTelephony= (ITelephony) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);

        try {
            iTelephony.answerRingingCall();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

Comment: this is a "possible" duplicate of [How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872557/7746134