how programmatically answer incoming call on speaker in MAUI
How to control Android phone from MAUI application? I need to answer some of incoming calls using phone speaker and some calls to reject.
It is required  to get call info details of incoming call and answer it on phone's speaker.
Thanks
UPDATE can answer on incoming call, but can not modify speaker on Android 14
Implemented Broadcast receiver:
[BroadcastReceiver( Enabled = true, Exported = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] {  TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class InterceptCall : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
   

    if (intent.Action == TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged)
    {
        var state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);
        var audioManager = (AudioManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)
        {
            
            //to delay speaker assigned
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>

                {
                    audioManager.Mode = Mode.InCall;
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Phone Off Hook", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;

                    });
                
            });

        }
        else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
        {
            
            string telephone = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Incoming call from " + telephone + ".", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Incoming call from unknown number.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

            //need permission to be able answer the call
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, new[] { Manifest.Permission.AnswerPhoneCalls }, 1);
            
            var telecomService = (TelecomManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.TelecomService);
            telecomService.AcceptRingingCall();
        
        }
        else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)
        {
            audioManager.Mode = Mode.Current;
            audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = false;
        }
    }

}

}

You are natively not allowed to pick up or reject calls programmatically...

I saw below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871673/how-to-answer-automatically-and-programatically-an-incoming-call-on-android and would like to implement same in MAUI

If your requirement is Android only then you can create the same broadcast receiver in the native Android Platforms folder and use it the same way you see in that answer.

correct I mention in question only Android. Looking for working example or sample

Did you grant the android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission? In addition, did it work in lower android version?

yes I did in android manifest and it is not working in any versions

I found that in android InCallService it is possible to set CallService.getInstance().setAudioRoute( speaker);
and it is working fine. Maybe exist a way to call setAudioRoute without InCallService ?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT any help ? I can provide sample project

You said you have resolved it with the InCallService.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT no - my InCallService (MauiAppSpeaker/Platforms/Android/MyIncallService.cs) is never called - I think it is not declared properly or needed to "say" something to device to use it.
As well as original problem that I can not change to speaker (no matter which API I use ( audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true
or audioManager.SetRouting(Mode.InCall, Route.Speaker, Route.All);
or     bool result = audioManager.SetCommunicationDevice(speaker);
I created sample project
https://github.com/vovanb/MauiAppSpeaker
please help as you can

If you use the InCallService, your app should be Default phone app.

can you review https://github.com/vovanb/MauiAppSpeaker and check why speaker is not changed?
in logcat I saw below message:
I  SamsungCallAudioRouteStateMachine: isSpeakerPhoneChangedByTelecom - modeOwner : com.android.server.telecom: CARSM.mSPCR@GWQ
2024-09-02 23:37:16.122  1386-1386  Telecom                 system_server                        I  SamsungCallAudioRouteStateMachine: ignore speaker change intent: CARSM.mSPCR@GWQ
